# how to work with APNS for Enterprise

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an application for an huge enterprise , I came to know about apple Enterprise programme for the in house distribution.

Using that I can control the iPhone through server. My server will connect with Apple server and then I can control the iPhone.

But can any one suggest me how the server will connect with the APNS and how my device will perform all the things ?

Be specific to the question : What code is needed on server as well as on iPhone so accomplish such kind of task like Mobile Device Management?

any tutorial or help will be great full..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no code. You need to purchase a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution from one of the 3rd parties listed on Apple's [MDM for iOS 4](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/mdm/) site. Or wait until Mac OS X Lion Server ships later this year.

One of the MDM providers [Airwatch](http://www.air-watch.com/platforms/iphone/index.html) is providing an SDK you include with your in-house app that ties back to Airwatch MDM server. You will need to speak to them for more details.

Comment: If I want to create a third party server then how I can ? any tutorial for that or any thing to create such things ?